# Affecting child elements by modifying the parent by CSS. is it possible?

Tags: css, hover

Maybe it's a silly question, but I'm sure it will be useful for many of beginners. I have constructed a code. What I'm trying to do is to display the text (in `<p>` tags) which is currently hidden, only when the actual `<a>` is hovered. Is this possible without js? Can it be done by operating on css / html only?
the html code is here:

```
                <div class="promo2">
                    <a href="speakers-hire.html">
                        <div class="promo2a">
                            <p>SPEAKERS</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a href="decks-hire.html">
                         <div class="promo2a">
                            <p>CD PLAYERS</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                </div>
```

and the css which correspond to the above html:

```
.promo2a:hover{
background:url(../_images/generic/glass5.png);
display:inline-block;
```

}

```
.promo2a p{
display:none;
```

}

So basically I want the text in `<p>` to be displayed when the whole div `promo2a` is hovered.

Any help is kindly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
.promo2a:hover > p {display:block;}
```

or whatever suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

You get pretty close, i just have to use :hover to display , ex:

```
.promo2a:hover p { display: block; }
```